# Button only works once and then breaks all other buttons on page too

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a large form with several buttons on it. Their purpose is to show/hide sections of the page (contained in UpdatePanels). They all use the same private method to do this (taking the button and the panel as arguments). And yet, two of my buttons behave diffrently from the rest. One of them just doesn't do anything. The other works once, but then stops all buttons from working from that point on.
If that button has been pressed, no button's onClick methods are called unless the page is reloaded (checked by debugging).

My button that breaks everything and its panel:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnBtCBerigelse" runat="server" Text="Vis" onClick="btnBtCBerigelse_Click"/>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlBtCBerigelse" runat="server" Visible="false" BorderColor="#99CCFF" BorderStyle="Solid">
   Content of panel
</asp:Panel>
```

The onClick method of that button (in the .cs file):

```
protected void btnBtCBerigelse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        visSkjul(btnBtCBerigelse, pnlBtCBerigelse);
    }
```

This method is called the first time I click that button, but not thereafter.

The method that it, and the other button's methods call (in same .cs file):

```
private void visSkjul(Button btn, Panel pnl)
    {
        if (pnl.Visible)
        {
            pnl.Visible = false;
            btn.Text = "Vis";
        }
        else
        {
            pnl.Visible = true;
            btn.Text = "Skjul";
        }
    }
```

Another button, supposed to be the same, but works just fine until the btnBtCBerigelse button has been clicked once:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnBtCEmne" runat="server" Text="Vis" onclick="btnBtCEmne_Click" />
<asp:Panel ID="pnlBtCEmne" runat="server" Visible="false" BorderColor="#99CCFF" BorderStyle="Solid">
    Content of panel
</asp:Panel>
```

Method of the button that works:

```
protected void btnBtCEmne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        visSkjul(btnBtCEmne, pnlBtCEmne);
    }
```

It calls the same private method as the other button.

The button that breaks everything even breaks the Save button on my page, Save doesn't use any panels or that private method.

What happens when this specific button is clicked that doesn't happen with all the others? The page worked before, and I don't think I changed anything except adding xml documentation (but that shouldn't change anything, right?).

The code of both the page and the .cs file in a google docs document: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1HhtSq5nXBio09pSBRsBWQbOM9m6Hr5wrNqhJ0O5Yf6s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint and debugging it?

Comment: Aren't attributes case-sensitive? Only mentioning because the code you posted that works has an "onclick=" attribute and the one you posted that doesn't work has an "onClick=" attribute.

Comment: Yes, that is why I know the onClick methods are never called after the button was clicked once.

Comment: Yes, they are, but I can't see anywhere I make that sort of mistake, I have copy-pasted all the names back and forth

Comment: In this line `<asp:Button ID="btnBtCBerigelse" runat="server" Text="Vis" onClick="btnBtCBerigelse_Click"/>` shouldn't that be `onclick="btnBtCBerigelse_Click"`?

Comment: onClick to onclick made no difference, the page behaves the same.

Comment: If that's the case then the problem has to be in some code that we can't see here - there is no reason it shouldn't work based on what you have posted so far.

Comment: What code would you like to see? Because I can't figure out why or where it would go wrong

Comment: Just noticed that the names of the button in the working example differ: `<asp:Button ID="btnBtCEmne" runat="server" Text="Vis" onclick="btnBtCEmne_Click" />
<asp:Panel ID="pnlBtCEmne" runat="server" Visible="false" BorderColor="#99CCFF" BorderStyle="Solid">
    Content of panel
</asp:Panel>` and `protected void btnBtBEmne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` I assume that is a typo, and they should both either be `btnBtBEmne` or `btnBtCEmne`? Also, I don't know you're code base so I have no idea what would be relevant here - posting too much info is better than too little.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1HhtSq5nXBio09pSBRsBWQbOM9m6Hr5wrNqhJ0O5Yf6s/edit?usp=sharing Both the page and the .cs file in their entirity in a google document.

Comment: Oh, sorry, that's because I posted the code from two buttons :P There are both a btnBtCEmne and a btnBtBEmne. I'll edit to show matching code.

Comment: Now it's just from the btnBtCEmne button (which works just fine until btnBtCBerigelse has been clicked)

Comment: Also, to clarify: I do not get any errors, it doesn't fail, nothing happens on the page or (apparently) in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A validator was causing the problem. I had added a validator on a field in the panel, and when this validator was not satisfied no buttons on the page would work.